# What should one do if they are being targeted by a single individual?

Tags: support, comments, down-votes, serial-voting

For the past few months, every one of my questions (total of eight) have been downvoted almost immediately after posting.  If they are poorly written questions or even if asking a question for something that shouldn't be attempted, I deserve and welcome the downvote.
 
I am not paranoid or a conspiracist, and while I have zero proof, it appears to have being done by a single individual.  My reason for thinking so is:

1. This didn't happen in the past and now is happening 100% of the time.
2. A single initial downvote occurs about 4 hours after the initial post.
3. They are downvoted only once, and are often later voted up.
4. Whoever downvotes never leaves a comment.

In an attempt to learn whether I am doing something wrong and deserve these downvotes, I've started leaving comments asking the reason for the downvote.  Not only do I not receive a reply to my comment, my comments are deleted by someone. Yesterday, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473888/multiple-key-identifiers-for-api-platform-resources), sure enough it was promptly downvoted, I left a comment but this time saved a screenshot of it, and like the rest it was gone by the time I woke up in the morning.

[image]

I have no formal software education and owe all that I have learned from the many generous members of this site, but now dread asking a question.  I am also not concerned about the loss of two votes, but I am concerned that questions with negative votes are less likely to be responded to by others, and feel I am now wasting my time asking a question.

What could I do?  As I see it, several options are:

1. No longer be a member of the stack platform.  Hopefully, not necessary.
2. Delete my existing account and create a new account.  If so, will I need to use a different email?
3. Aggressively add large bounties until I have very few votes and hopefully fall off their radar.  I have started doing so with no avail.
4. Have someone who can query the DB determine whether it is only a single individual who is systematically downvoting my questions and deleting my comments (I don't even want to know who) and if so ask them to stop.

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: There's absolutely no chance of #4 happening. Voting is anonymous for a reason. These types of downvotes are pretty common, especially on SO. Mods will delete comments asking for explanations for downvotes as the likelihood of someone bothering to do so who hasn't done it when downvoting is incredibly low. The best thing to do here is just to shrug it off and continue posting

Comment: You need to follow the guidance from the answer to the question I linked, under "What if I think I'm the victim of voting fraud?", and raise a 'in need of moderator intervention flag' on one of the downvoted posts.  Be prepared for this not being from 1 person though, in which case there's nothing moderators can do. I'd recommend against any of your 4 options then though, and just remember that [people lose their keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/369802) and carry on. Especially if your posts are upvoted at a later time.

Comment: @rene  I don't understand.  Should I not be using such a tag if the question is not dedicated to PHP but revolves around an application such as Symfony?  Please elaborate.

Comment: I think @rene is not too fond of PHP, it makes his petals wilt even more ;)

Comment: @user1032531 Just as a quick note, rene was joking. Well, mostly, anyway. ;)

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing  As I stated, I don't want to know the identify and agree it should remain anonymous.  I've been doing as you say and shrugging it off, but it is becoming a non-option for me.  A more viable option is to either get rid of my votes are create a new account with zero votes and start over.

Comment: @rene  Ha, ha.  Got it!  Been just a bit defensive lately.  Thanks!

Comment: A quick analysis shows that almost 30% of new PHP questions get a down vote: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1406952 (assuming I got that query right)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell  Thanks for the link as well as the lost keys story (never new about this).  Will do as you say.   And I am prepared and actually hope that it isn't anything sinister.

Comment: @rene  Wow, you mean individual's can run their own queries against the SO DB?  What happened about voter anonymity?

Comment: Well - they can't see who voted, just what was voted for, if that makes sense.

Comment: @user1032531 it’s impossible to know who cast those votes (unless you’re a moderator) (also see Journeyman Geeks comment)

Comment: @JourneymanGeek just admit I'm awesome and call it a day ...

Comment: @EkadhSingh we can't really see which votes are for what question either. We can *very roughly* see a subset of voting trends. If its fishy, we'd pass it on to the CMs.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell  Crap, I don't think I should have asked this question on meta: "... do not ask about serial voting on a site's meta. ... result in people engaging in additional targeted voting."  Also, had a hard time finding this "moderator intervention" flag (searched for "mod" but none), but just found it.  Thanks